# Get value from Redis using Jmeter Redis Data Set

Tags: java, redis, jmeter, escaping, key-value

I try to get value from Redis using Redis Data Set plugin in Jmeter. If the Redis key is simple (as in Example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0vu3tfrdKc), its value is extracted without any problems. In my case, the value is stored in the complex key, like - **user.confirmation.6869427a27e784f7e7cbb0746714c27d** and when I use it as the value of "Redis Key:" in Redis Data Set the following message pops up on the screen while the script is not performed and jmeter key value wouldn't return:

```
2017/02/11 12:57:57 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2017/02/11 12:57:57 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2017/02/11 12:57:57 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*)
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group User Service
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group User Service.
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will start next loop on error
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group User Service 1-1
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of redis data detected, thread will exit 
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group User Service 1-1 
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2017/02/11 12:57:58 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Besides there is no problem in receiving the value in Redis console itself.
Attempts to screen the dots in the key come to no avail as well.
I looking forward to hearing from you with any comment.

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

To test, I created a Redis (key,value) set like this:

```
key: user.confirmation.6869427a27e784f7e7cbb0746714c27d 
row1: user.confirmation.6869427a27e784f7e7cbb0746714c27d
row2: test
```

And I could retrieve both rows data with Redis Data Set, so it seams that the issue is not related to the long name, but maybe this name is not the same in your Redis data store and JMeter. That is why JMeter complains: "**End of redis data detected, thread will exit**"

Comment: This solution works fine when Redis values stored in List or Set datatype. But in my way used String.